# how to make a inputfield as required?

Tags: visualforce, apexinputfield

i have two table.one with apex tag another with HTML tag.in the both table i need my fields as required.eg:i want to make my input field as required.so am giving required="true" in .but while giving this the HTML tag table doesn't work.

Page :

```
<apex:page standardController="RFLEET_Protocol_Grid__c" extensions="RFLEET_ProtocolDynamicGrid" id="pge">

<apex:form id="frm" >

<script>
function dispalydivfun()
{
document.getElementById('dipslaydiv').style.display="block";
var radios = document.getElementsByName('md');
for (i = 0; i < radios .length; i++) {
radios[i].disabled = true;
radios[i].checked = false;
}
document.getElementById('infoDetailSecondLabel').style.display = 'none';
var Style = document.getElementById("btn").disabled=true;
document.getElementById("edName").required = true;
return false;
}
function Delete() {
hideshow();
}
</script>

<apex:actionFunction name="hideshow" action="{!Delrecords}"/>
<apex:pageblock rendered="{!showgrid}" id="pb" >
<apex:pageBlockButtons location="TOP" id="pbBtn">
<input type = "button" value="{!$Label.New_Line}" onclick="dispalydivfun()" />
<input type = "button" value="{!$Label.Delete1}" onclick="Delete()" id="btn"/> 
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
<apex:dataTable value="{!protocolgrid}" var="allcon" cellpadding="4" border="1" >
<apex:column headervalue="" > 
<apex:outputPanel id="re"> 
<input type="radio" name="md" id="targetRadio1" />
<apex:actionsupport action="{!selectcon}" event="onclick" rerender="consel" >  
<apex:param name="conid" value="{!allcon.Id}" assignTo="{!conid}"/> 
</apex:actionsupport>  </apex:outputPanel>  
</apex:column>                        
<apex:column value="{!allcon.Model__c}" headervalue="{!$Label.Model1}"  />
<apex:column value="{!allcon.Discount__c}" headervalue="{!$Label.Discount}" />
</apex:dataTable>
</apex:pageblock>

<div id="dipslaydiv" style="display:none;">
<apex:pageBlock mode="maindetail" >
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="2"> 
<apex:inputField value="{!proo.Model__c}" />
<apex:inputField value="{!proo.Discount__c}" />
</apex:pageBlockSection>
<apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
<apex:commandButton action="{!Newlinesave}" value="{!$Label.Save3}"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
</apex:pageBlock>
</div>
<!--------------slected radio values display here------------->
<div id="infoDetailSecondLabel">
<apex:pageblock id="consel" mode="maindetail" >
<apex:outputPanel id="infoDetailSecondLabel" style="float:right;" layout="none" rendered="{!showgrid}">
<apex:dataTable id="allcons" value="{!selectedContact}" var="selcon" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="8" bgcolor="WHITESMOKE">
<apex:column >
<label >{!$Label.Model1}</label>
<div class="requiredInput" style="display:inline-block"> <div class="requiredBlock"></div>
<input id="modeldiscount" value="{!selcon.Model__c}" name = "Model1" required="required"/>
</div>
</apex:column>
<apex:commandButton value="{!$Label.Save3}" action="{!Selectedval}"/>
</apex:column> 
</apex:dataTable>
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:pageblock>
</div>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: can you share your code. What have you tried.

Comment: i have shared my code above

Comment: apex:inputField in this field i can't find the required attribute. Where is the exact problem.

Comment: in case i gave the required attribute in  
apex:input Field  .the HTML tag table i.e <div id="infoDetailSecondLabel"> this table is not working

Comment: and what thing is not working if you give required attribute.

Comment: yea exactly.the HTML tag table doesn't work.the HTML tag table is nothing but the selected radio values are displayed below the datatable.but it is not displayed when am giving required

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="dipslaydiv" style="display:none;">
<apex:pageBlock mode="maindetail" >
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="2"> 
<apex:inputField value="{!proo.Model__c}" />
<apex:inputField value="{!proo.Discount__c}" />
</apex:pageBlockSection>
<apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
<apex:commandButton action="{!Newlinesave}" value="{!$Label.Save3}"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
</apex:pageBlock>
</div>
```

I think I have found your problem . The problem is if you mark the field required then you must fill them but as your div style display:none. I think you don't fill value in them. also as there is no **Pagemessage** in your page so error is also not display on the page. So when you don't fill them value it don't allow to submit your request and thats why your table is not working. Now your have two workarounds.

1. you can use immediate attribute in command button or in any action function.
2. Conditionally make required attribute true or false.
   Hope this will help you.

Comment: immediate attribute and required attribute used in same <div id="dipslaydiv" style="display:none;"> table